# Entity namespace subclass not working in Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, namespaces, doctrine

I am using Doctrine with Composer.

I have the following code on base class:

```
Entidades\BaseTable.php...
<?php
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @MappedSuperclass
 */
class BaseTable
{
    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Column(type="datetime")
     * @var datetime
     */
    protected $criado_em;

    public function __construct()
    {
        date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Melbourne');
        $this->criado_em = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo'));
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
?>
```

And on the final class I got:

```
Entidades\Sistema\Aplicativo.php...
<?php
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

namespace Entidades\Sistema;

/**
 * @Entity @Table(name="sistema.aplicativos")
 */
class Aplicativo Extends \Entidades\BaseTable
{
    /**
     * @Column(type="string", nullable=false)
     * @var string
     */
    public $nome;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", unique=true, nullable=false)
     * @var string
     */
    public $app_key;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", unique=true, nullable=false)
     * @var string
     */
    public $esquema;

    public function addAplicativo($nome,$esquema)
    {
        $this->nome = $nome;
        $this->esquema = $esquema;
    }

    protected function newGuid()
    {
        if (function_exists('com_create_guid') === true)
        {
            return trim(com_create_guid(), '{}');
        }
        return sprintf('%04X%04X-%04X-%04X-%04X-%04X%04X%04X', mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0,     65535), mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(16384, 20479), mt_rand(32768, 49151), mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535));
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->app_key = newGuid();
    }
}
?>
```

When I use the command `php vendor/doctrine/orm/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create` on project root it create everything fine. But when I do something like:

```
<?php
require_once "bootstrap.php";

$novo = new Sistema\Aplicativo();
$novo->nome = 'Teste';
$novo->esquema = 'Teste';

$entityManager->persist($novo);
$entityManager->flush();

echo "Aplicativo com o ID " . $product->getId() . " criado com sucesso.\n";
?>
```

PHP throws an error like:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Entidades\BaseTable' not found in PROJECTPATH\Entidades\Sistema\Aplicativo.php on line 10
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  127464  {main}( )   ..\addAplicativo.php:0
2   0.0775  2090656 Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass( ) ..\addAplicativo.php:0
3   0.0775  2090760 Composer\Autoload\includeFile( )    ..\ClassLoader.php:274
4   0.0782  2098408 include( 'D:\TRABALHO\Admin v3\Server\Entidades\Sistema\Aplicativo.php' )           ..\ClassLoader.php:382
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

The problem was with composer autoload...

I have make a mistake there, the solution was to put in the autoload, the psd-4 with the namespaces, the psr-0 don´t worked as espected... but psr-4 yes...

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "": "Entidades/",
        "Entidades\\": "Entidades/",
        "Entidades\\Sistema\\": "Entidades/Sistema/"
    }
}
```

tnx for your time ppl.